# How to match last occurrence using lookaround Regex in Sublime 3?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-lookarounds

I am using sublime 3. I would like to match only last occurrence of " (128 Kbps) ".I want to get this done with lookaround function of regex. I have tried couple of but could not be able to get desire result.

Input:

```
C:\Abc\Baar Baar Dekho (2016)\Dariya (128 Kbps) - Arko.mp3  Dariya (128 Kbps) - Arko.mp3@C:\Abc\Baar Baar Dekho (2016)\Dariya (128 Kbps) - Arko.mp3  Dariya (128 Kbps) - Arko.mp3
```

Desire Output:

```
Last Occurrence of " (128 Kbps) ".
```

I have tried following Regex.

```
(?<=@.*)( 128 Kbps)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\(128 Kbps\)(?!.*\(128 Kbps\))
```

match the literal `(128 Kbps)` where it is not followed by `(128 Kbps)` anywhere after it

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds.